# Is there a way to make a multi-client server app without using multiple thread?

Tags: java

I'm making a multi-client server chat application with Java.

Is there any way to not use multi-threads (1 thread for every client)?
Because my app runs on mobile, so multi-thread  will make it too slow?

Comment: Just checking: Is the "chat server" running on a mobile device too?

Comment: A server application need to be running all the time. A mobile device is not suitable from running such a service because you will quickly run out of power.  What you want on a mobile device is a chat *client* which only needs one or two threads.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are misunderstanding the concept. A chat app intended to run on mobile device normally works like follows:

1. You will have a chat server, which is **not** in mobile application, hosted somewhere. This will communicate with client applications on different mobile devices.
2. In mobile client application, you will connect to chat server and process the data accordingly. This communication is generally done by socket connection.
3. Here every application acts individually so you do ***not*** need multi-thread in mobile application except any other functionality in your app need multi-threading. You can consider each application as different thread connecting on server socket.

Answer (score 0):

For not mobile application some people use awesome [Netty](https://netty.io/) client-server (me too). Probably 
some ideas of this server helps you to create right architecture :)